# Previous marker remove in google map

Tags: javascript, php

Tried to create moving marker. But the marker create new not moving the same. I want moving marker with remove previous marker

```
function makeMarker(map) { 
     var icons = 'images/tvsxl.png';

  setInterval(function(){   var markers = []; 
    $.post( "ajaxload.php?shop_id=<?php echo $outlet_id?>", function(data) {  
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        var value = obj['data'];
        //console.log(value.length);
        for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {  

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(value[i].latitude ,value[i].longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: myLatLng, map: map,icon: icons,title:value[i].name} );

        markers.push(marker); 
        markers[i].setMap( map );

         }  


    }); 

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear old markers before placing a new ones

```
for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
         markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    //clear old markers form array
    markers = [];
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but how can i use.not workingfor (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {  
  markers[i].setMap(null); 
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(value[i].latitude ,value[i].longitude);

Comment: I am not sure i understood your question well. Would you care to elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
markers[marker-index-value].setMap( null);
```

Comment: Thx to reply. not working i used.
for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {  
  markers[i].setMap(null);

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.